# Do all canonical com system interfaces end with -0000-0000-c000-000000000046?

Tags: windows, winapi, com

Do all canonical com system interfaces end with -0000-0000-c000-000000000046?

Guids are supposed to be generated at random but browsing the registry the canonical COM system interfaces such as IUnknown {00000000-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}, IClassFactory {00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}, IDispatch {00020400-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} have a pattern.

Is there an API function called `IsSystemInterface()` or something that I can call to test.  Or should I just string compare the tail?

EDIT: about the use case, there will be no type library for these canonical interfaces and so they need to be screened out.

Comment: "*Do all canonical com system interfaces end with ...*" - you would have to ask Microsoft about that. "*Is there an API function...*" - no, there is not. "*they need to be screened out*" - when processing interfaces, why not simply check for the existence of a `HKCR\Interface\<iid>\TypeLib` key in the Registry?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : yeah, pretty much agree.  I wanted to avoid hitting the registry so many times.

Comment: Not sure it counts as a canonical system interface, but [IInspectable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/inspectable/nn-inspectable-iinspectable)'s GUID is AF86E2E0-B12D-4c6a-9C5A-D7AA65101E90. Doesn't come with a TypeLib either. Besides, GUID's aren't necessarily generated at random. Windows Runtime GUID's are predictable, generated from the fully qualified type name. The GUID's you mentioned are in a range reserved by Microsoft (`c` in octet 8), so they can do whatever they please. See [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) for details.

Comment: @IInspectable : ok, I think RFC 4122 is an acceptable answer.  If you upgrade to answer I will accept and upvote.  Then I can get off unanswered queue.

Comment: If your use case is that you need to know if a COM IID has a registered Typelib, you have to look it up. I know it looks like a lot of computing work. But COM IID are opaque numbers; trying to guess based on the IID value is doing it wrong. Of course you can optimize something to be faster by doing it wrong, but that doesn't make it "not wrong". You will get both false positives and false negatives.

Comment: The information contained in RFC 4122 may solve your immediate issue, but does not constitute an answer to the question that was asked. You would have to ask a different question so that that comment is a valid and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no guarantee of this.

A bunch of the original system COM interfaces do have that form, but most if not all new ones don't.

E.g. the original `IShellFolder`:

`DEFINE_GUID(IID_IShellFolder,        0x000214E6L, 0, 0, 0xC0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0x46);`

The later extended interface, `IShellFolder2`:

`DEFINE_GUID(IID_IShellFolder2,  0x93f2f68c, 0x1d1b, 0x11d3, 0xa3, 0xe, 0x0, 0xc0, 0x4f, 0x79, 0xab, 0xd1);`

Answer (score 0):

Some [C++ code](http://en.verysource.com/code/10359721_1/ipserver.h.html) lines 89-210 show an optimization that is possible because those interfaces share the same suffix.

```
// 
// the first dword of GUIDs for most of the interesting interfaces.  these are
// used by speed critical versions of QueryInterface 
//
#define Data1_IAdviseSink                  0x0000010f
#define Data1_IAdviseSink2                 0x00000125
#define Data1_IAdviseSinkEx                0x3af24290
...
```